# Extract IP with sed from command

Tags: linux, sed

I've a string which looks like:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-31-generic HTTP_BOOT=192.168.1.133 root=UUID=b4 ro quiet splash
```

*In example "/proc/cmdline"*

I would like to extract HTTP_BOOT with sed. My current sed command looks like that.

```
HTTP_BOOT=$(sed -r 's/^.*HTTP_BOOT=(.*?).*/\1/' /proc/cmdline)
```

The var HTTP_BOOT should contain 192.168.1.133.
Would be really happy if someone could correct my sed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
HTTP_BOOT=$(sed 's/.*HTTP_BOOT=\([^ ]*\) .*/\1/' < /proc/cmdline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Try this sed:

```
sed -r 's/^.*HTTP_BOOT=([^\ ]*).*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP_BOOT=$(egrep -o 'HTTP_BOOT=[1-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' /proc/cmdline | cut -d '=' -f 2)`

Also does a nice minor sanity check on the IP